# Tab not appearing unless clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `<select>` element to display a container with info. Using JQuery I display the selected container and hide the rest. In the container I have three `<div>` elements.

1. Description
2. Measurement in CM
3. Measurement in Inches.

The user has the ability to select which measurement unit to see by clicking on the different tabs. So far it all works great. It does display the info as wanted, however when I re-select different size I can not see any of the tabs info unless I click on one of them. In other words to re-create the issue:

1. Select size
2. Change the measurement units
3. Re-select size
4. Unless clicked none of the tab will show the info

To make it easier to understand I've created [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/znjyq8he/).

Can someone possibly have an idea how to keep the cm tab open by default even after the size was re-selected?

Comment: You want the `centimeters` tab to be shown by default?

Comment: @John If you solved the issue, please add it in an answer rather than update the question.

Comment: @DrewGaynor it seems that I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some new class to the input checkbox tag (.cm and .in respectively)

```
<div class="d-tab"><input checked="checked" id="tab-6" class="cm" name="tab-group-2" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-6">&nbsp;Centimeters&nbsp;</label>
```

I also added a new function when selecting on the select size. This function to keep track which measurement is active.

```
$(".cm, .in").click(function(){
    $(".cm, .in").removeClass("active");       
    if($(this).hasClass("cm")){
        $(".cm").addClass("active");
    else
        $(".in").addClass("active");            
});
```

Lastly I tweaked the css to show the active state

```
[type=radio]:checked ~ label,
.cm.active ~ label,
.in.active ~ label{
  background: #dbd7d7;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .measurement-content,
.cm.active ~ label ~ .measurement-content,
.in.active ~ label ~ .measurement-content{
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/a1jnLq49/

Comment: I want to have the cm open by default. Currently I need to click on one of them to activate the tabs

Comment: Ah, you only need to add     $(".cm").addClass("active");

Comment: Oh, I remove these two lines from the css **[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .measurement-content,** and **[type=radio]:checked ~ label,** http://jsfiddle.net/o57kf2wd/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Its working.
http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/yjaoccmb/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('#community').change(function () {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected');

        var valuer = $(this).val();

        $("#tabs-" + valuer).prop('checked', true);

        $('#size-single1').toggle(option.hasClass('show1'));
        $('#size-single2').toggle(option.hasClass('show2'));

    }).change();
});
```

Comment: It seems that this didn't help.

Comment: @John this will select your radio button initial. When you select the value from dropdown box. Something like this: 

$('#community').change(function() {
$('#tab-4').prop('checked', true); 
}

Comment: It does work the only issue is that there is an ID assign to it and will change only the #tab-4.

Comment: Make one class of all radio which has cm parameter. And used it.
           $(input[class=someClassname])